# Values which are changed in Jquery, are not showing up on codebehind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

- ASP.NET 4
- Jquery 1.7.1
- Browser: IE9

Hi

I am using jquery with a gridview control inside a UpdatePanel so, everytime I click on a row of the gridview Jquery edits the value of a HiddenField control, so when I need "the selected index", I just use the value of the HiddenField. And everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE9. After clicking a row and assigning it's index to the HiddenField, when I click a button and fire a server side event, when I retrieve the HiddenField's value, I get its default value (the one defined in the mark-up), and not the changed one. And, strangely, if I use and alert(HiddenField.value), it shows me the row index! so, the problem only occurs on the server side function, even after the postback the HiddenField value is preserved, but always as default on server side...

This is my Jquery code:

```
$('[id$=divtxtIdPresentacion]').click(function () {

             var tex = $('#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>').attr("Value");

             var index = $(this).attr("commandargument");             

             if (tex != index) {

                 $('#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>').attr("Value", index);
             }

         });
```

And part of the button event:

```
 protected void gridPresentacionAgregar_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       

         int index = int.Parse(HFSeleccionIndexRow.Value);
         ...
     }
```

And the HiddenField (just in case):

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HFSeleccionIndexRow" value="0" />
```

Comment: Yes, I have used alert(something) to determine it, as I said, it works fine on other browsers

Comment: Yes, I just tested both of them just to be sure

Comment: Ok, Is your hidden input fields are within the update panel control? If not, try moving the hidden fields within the `<ContentTemplate>` tag and test it again.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks you so much! This was killing me since yesterday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hidden input fields are not within the update panel control. Any asynchronous round trips to the server will cause only those controls within the `UpdatePanel` itself to update on the UI, so even though the code-behind runs and updates the hidden fields, on the front end they stay the same because they sit outside the panel.

Try moving the hidden fields within the `<ContentTemplate>` tag:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTripsGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HFSeleccionIndexRow" value="0" />
        .....
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use jQuery code for selected index changed. You have used update panel so no server trip will be shown to user.

It is better to use command argument, command name and fire server side click.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm wrong, but with the update panel at least a partial postback will be fired, meaning the there would a server trip, isn't it? (although I was thinking of doing that, this bug is killing me..)

Comment: With update panel, full server trip will be fire but only code which is in update panel will change. If you have dropdown list outside update panel then that will not change and its value remain same. If you fire jquery call then how can you bind grid after changing data?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value like this:

```
    $('[id$=divtxtIdPresentacion]').click(function () {

         var tex = $('#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>').attr("Value");

         var index = $(this).attr("commandargument");             

         if (tex != index) {
           $('#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>').val(index);
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this jquery function instead

```
$('[id$=divtxtIdPresentacion]').click(function () {
    var tex = $('#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>').attr("Value");
    var index = $(this).attr("commandargument");             
    if (tex != index) {
        if($.browser.msie){
             $("#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>").prop("defaultValue", index);
        }
        else{
             $('#<%=HFSeleccionIndexRow.ClientID%>').attr("Value", index);
        }
    }
});
```